# Why do I need to const_cast when releasing memory for a const data

Tags: c++

While releasing memory of a const data, why do I need to const_cast it. What will be the result If I ignore it.

Comment: Can you please show an example? Including declaration of any involved variables.

Comment: It depends on the prototype of the function you call to release the memory.

Comment: What's "releasing memory?" Show some code, please.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. This is completely valid, standard conform, code:

```
int const * const a = new int(42);
delete a;
```

It sounds like you are using `std::free` from `<cstdlib>` to do this instead, which signature is

```
void free(void *);
```

In this case the implicit conversion from `int const * const` to `void *` fails because you can only implicit const-cast, not cast const away. You want the first version in C++ anyway.